# Printing only the vowels in string. (Swift 5.1)

Tags: swift, foreach

I need to print just the vowels in this string. I have created a var for the vowels and did an if statement and hade no luck. I tried to pull each vowel by its placement value and couldn't find a way to make it work. I am very new to this and have spent 6 hours trying to look it up and see what works. I know I'm not understanding something or maybe even all of it. Please help!

```
let scc = "Spokane Community College Software Development"
scc.forEach { scc in
    print(scc.lowercased() )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
let arr = ["u","i","e","a","o"]
let str = "Spokane Community College Software Development"
str.forEach {
   if arr.contains($0.lowercased()) {
      print($0)
   }
}
```

Comment: You forgot the "o", also i dont know if it makes a big difference to make the vowels array just a string i.e "aeiou".

Comment: “You can try” isn’t much of an explanation to someone who is a complete beginner. And also, maybe you should add ‘y’ to your array.

Comment: $0 is an int value correct? I'm confused on why it's used instead of the str to find a char in a string. or is it creating a new variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
 func vowel(_ input :String)
{

    for i in  input
    {

        if(i == "a" || i == "e" || i == "i" || i == "u" || i == "o")
        {
print(i)

        }

    }

}
vowel("Spokane Community College Software Development")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll have to look everything up to make sure I get a complete understand on how and why it works

Answer (score 0):

```
var vowelCount = 0
var vowels = Set(["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"])

func count_vowels(input: String) -> Int {

for ch in input {
    
    if (vowels.contains(ch.lowercased())) {
        
    vowelCount += 1
  }
    else {
        
    }
}
return vowelCount
}

count_vowels(input: "test12222 voWeL !+COUNT")
```